# Crystal Reports - display caption from dataset, not column name

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that is is simply from a DataSet which I populate at runtime. The problem is, on the report I want some of the columns to have different capations - for example, I have the following fields in my report

```
Sell Total
Profit Total
Net Total
```

I want all of these columns to be displayed just as 'Total' on my report - I have tried setting the 'Caption' property but Crystal seems to ignore this, and there appears to be no way on the IFIeldObject to change the text.

Comment: Do you want to add the three columns' values together?  Or do you want 3 individual columns, each with 'Total' as the column header?

Answer (score 0):

Chris,

It's a bit tricky to visualize what you are trying to do. That said, one route might be to actually just hide the fields that Crystal Reports is using and make your own formula driven labels in the group/section footer, or whatever area you see these in.

Unless I've misunderstood, and it is somewhere that can't have the captions replaced easily (charts come to mind).

Comment: Hey Dylan, welcome to SO! In case your signature gets removed and wondered why http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'm stripping them out of the answers I provided today. Where is the 'comment' option found? I saw it here on YOUR comment, but I've never seen that on people's questions and posts. Is it only shown if my reputation is higher?

Comment: Thanks again, it's a lot of information to absorb all at once!